# A combinatorial solving problem

Tags: combinatorics

The value of  $$\frac{ \sum_{i=0}^{100} \dbinom{k}{i} \dbinom{M-k}{100-i} \frac{k-i}{M-100} }{\dbinom{M}{100}} $$ Where $M-K > 100, K > 100$ and $\dbinom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!{(m-n)}!}$ equals,

(a) $\frac{k}{M}$

(b) $\frac{M}{k}$

(c) $\frac{k}{2M}$

(d) $\frac{M}{2k}$

---

Now I tried to solve it by the way of direct solving and simplifying it but I am stuck and can't solve it till the end... Can I have help?

Comment: What happens if you explore substituting the number $(4)$ for the number $(100)$, throughout the problem?  It would be reasonable to surmise that there is nothing special about the number $(100)$ in the assertion.  Note that this is a problem solving task, not an analytical proof task.  The creative approach that I am suggesting may have been the problem composer's intended challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

Use that $(k-i)\dbinom{k}{i}=\frac{k!}{i!(k-i-1)!}=k\frac{(k-1)!}{i!(k-i-1)!}=k\dbinom{k-1}{i}$ and [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

$${n+m \choose k} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}{n \choose j}{m \choose k-j}$$

Answer (score 1):

A drawer has $K$ red marbles and $M-K$ green marbles. Suppose you take a sample of $100$ marbles from the drawer without replacement; let $X$ denote the number of red marbles that you obtain. Then $X$ possesses a hypergeometric distribution and $\mathbb{E}(X)= \frac{100K}{M}$.

The expression you need to compute actually equals $$\mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{K-X}{M-100}\Big)=\frac{K}{M}$$